Chakra UI: Help on scrollable tab content needed
In Chakra UI version 2, I have the following Tabs component whose content overflows instead of being scrollable:
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Box
        width={300}
        height={300}
        borderWidth={2}
        borderRadius="lg"
        margin={4}
        padding={2}
      >
        <Flex direction="column">
          <Box flex="1">
            <Tabs height="full" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
              <TabList>
                <Tab>Tab 1</Tab>
                <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
              </TabList>
              <TabPanels overflowY="scroll">
                <TabPanel>
                  <Text>Content for Tab 1</Text>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel>
                  <LoremIpsum />
                </TabPanel>
              </TabPanels>
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

The result looks like this:

The code will actually work if the Flex and the inner Box component surrounding the Tabs component are removed:
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Box
        width={300}
        height={300}
        borderWidth={2}
        borderRadius="lg"
        margin={4}
        padding={2}
      >
        {/*<Flex direction="column">*/}
          {/*<Box flex="1">*/}
            <Tabs height="full" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
              <TabList>
                <Tab>Tab 1</Tab>
                <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
              </TabList>
              <TabPanels overflowY="scroll">
                <TabPanel>
                  <Text>Content for Tab 1</Text>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel>
                  <LoremIpsum />
                </TabPanel>
              </TabPanels>
            </Tabs>
          {/*</Box>*/}
        {/*</Flex>*/}
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}


However, these two components originate from other parts of the code, and I only added them to create a minimal working example and narrow down the problem. They unfortunately cannot be removed.
What is causing these issues and how do I fix them?
Click here for a working copy (give it some 30 seconds to load).
(Thanks to any answer in advance, this has been bugging me for quite some time now.)

One needs to make sure that all parent components specify their height. Specifically, as soon as the height="full" prop is added to both the Flex and the Box component that had been removed in the second example, the layout issue resolves and the tab content will indeed scroll:
function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Box
        width={300}
        height={300}
        borderWidth={2}
        borderRadius="lg"
        margin={4}
        padding={2}
      >
        <Flex height="full" direction="column">
          <Box height="full" flex="1">
            <Tabs height="full" display="flex" flexDirection="column">
              <TabList>
                <Tab>Tab 1</Tab>
                <Tab>Tab 2</Tab>
              </TabList>
              <TabPanels overflowY="scroll">
                <TabPanel>
                  <Text>Content for Tab 1</Text>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel>
                  <LoremIpsum />
                </TabPanel>
              </TabPanels>
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

